# Link LaTeX output warnings back to Problems View in Texlipse / arara

Tags: texlipse, arara, eclipse

I am using arara to compile my latex sources in Eclipse using Texlipse.

Is there any way to re-direct the warnings generated into the "Problems View" of Eclipse as it happens when one uses the default builder provided by Texlipse?

In principle, the error messages are relayed and it seems to work correctly.